# CoreMIDI on the command line

Tags: c++, macos, midi, coremidi

I've started working on a command-line app based on RtMidi that can send arbitrary MIDI data. I've found that, while I can talk to MIDI devices when I run the tool from the console, if I ssh in to my machine from another, I can't get any MIDI functionality to work at all. To be specific, RtMidi makes a call to `MIDIClientCreate()` which returns error code -10839, which is not documented anywhere that I could find. I've tried duplicating the environment variables of working process, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code -10839 corresponds to the symbol named `kMIDIServerStartErr`. I suspect that the CoreMIDI server requires a connection to SystemUIServer (ie, a graphical login).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I need a more complicated approach, bah!

Comment: FWIW, I've not had this problem using CoreMIDI from a console app under MacOS 10.11 or later